# removing and reinstalling windows 10 along side linux

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, bootloader

I have installed Arch Linux on `nvme0n1p5` and windows 10 is on `nvme0n1p4`. Also as far as I remember I installed the grub bootloader on `nvme0n1p2` i.e. `boot/efi` along with windows boot

Now I want do a fresh install of windows 10 by removing this existing one. What do you think should be the right way of doing this? I haven't done it before so I don't the exact process

I can start by formatting `nvme0n1p4` i.e. windows ntfs drive and boot from pendrive and again install windows bootloader in `nvme0n1p2` for fresh install

but will that mess-up grub or something? Should I first clean windows bootloader from `nvme0n1p2` Or should be fine?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that Windows Boot Manager will be reordered to the top/first option in the boot priority/menu, so you'll probably need to reorder grub to that in the UEFI firmware settings.

It's probably better for you to delete the `Microsoft` directory under `EFI` of the ESP (probably mounted to either `/boot` or `/boot/efi`, in case the installer simply add a boot entry to the BCD instead of recreating the whole file.

Comment: makes sense thanks :)